# C: dup and close-on-exec

Tags: c, unix, dup

In a (German) book about C programming (Linux-UNIX-Programmierung, by Jürgen Wolf) I have found a statement, which translated to English would be as following (sentences numbered by me):

> In some cases it can be necessary that you need to duplicate a file descriptor [1]. An example for this would be, if a parent process wants to exchange data with a child process and the child process is overlaid by a new process through the use of `exec*()` [2]. In such a case, without `dup() or dup2()`, the *close-on-exec* flag would be set [3]. When this flag is set, all file descriptors become invalid (since being overlaid by the new process) - that is, they are not present anymore [4]. The communication between the parent and child process would thus be stopped [5]. If on the other hand you duplicate the file descriptor with `dup() or dup2()`, then the *close-on-exec* flag is deleted, and the newly overlaid process can use this file descriptor to communicate [6].

I believe that the above paragraph contains several misleading statements or even errors.

In sentence [3], I do not understand why without the use of `dup()` or `dup2()` the *close-on-exec* flag would be set?

Comment: Maybe they're talking about a library function, which doesn't know which descriptors the caller has set the *close-on-exec* flag for, so it has to assume the worst.

Comment: Also, the library shouldn't change the state of file descriptors that the caller is using.

Comment: @Barmar unless it's his purpose, ncurses, libcaca, etc.

Comment: [3] seems to imply the COE flag was set by default, which it isn't. But it's not actually *saying* this and not actually excluding that someone might have  set it deliberately before. Agree, however, that this is at least misleading.

Comment: Is there some prior context that indicates that the file descriptors under discussion have the FD_CLOEXEC (or O_CLOEXEC) flag set?  If not, it is probably mildly confused; FD_CLOEXEC is not set by default.

Comment: I just read this up in the original (http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/linux_unix_programmierung/Kap02-002.htm#RxxKap02002040000CC1F023214 for anyone who can read German), and yes, this actually seems to be messed up. The paragraph *really* sounds as if COE were the default.

Comment: "When **this flag** is set, **all** file descriptors become invalid" - It really sounds like this is saying there is one flag for the entire process, which is all kinds of wrong!

Comment: @tofro Thanks for reading this up in German and confirming that its messed up. I was already starting to doubt my understanding of C and IPC.

Comment: You didn't read on: It continues "If you don't completely follow this or don't get it at all, that's not so important now" :) Nice book!

Comment: There are *many* terrible books on C. The tough part is finding a good one. I'm partial to the C11 draft standard n1570 myself, and the POSIX standard for POSIX-related topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advice is wrong.  Close-on-exec is set only on file descriptors that your program has explicitly asked to be close-on-exec.

The reasons you may choose to use `dup2` may be:

- The process to be executed expects its I/O to be via particular file descriptors (usually 0, 1, and 2, corresponding to standard input, output and error streams respectively), or
- the process will close some file descriptors, for whatever reason, and you need this fd to be outside the range to be closed.

The description is also slightly misleading - it's only the new descriptor (i.e. the return value from `dup()` or `dup2()`) which has close-on-exec unset.  The close-on-exec state of the original fd is unchanged.